# Find a basis for $\mathbb Q(i \sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb Q$ and describe its elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find a basis for $\mathbb Q(i \sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb Q$ and describe its elements.

So I need to find a minimum polynomial of $i\sqrt{s}$ over $\mathbb Q$ which I believe has degree 2 (I don't know why or how to find it I'm lost on this topic). Then I need to find a linear combination using the minimum polynomial and that will be the elements of the basis. I know for $\mathbb Q\sqrt{2}$ that the elements are of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$. Would $\mathbb Q (i\sqrt{2})$ consist of elements of the form $a+bi\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes, the elements would be of the form $a + bi\sqrt2$. However, we need conclusive proof that that covers all of it. How do we know that it's not $a + bi\sqrt2 + c(i\sqrt2)^2+d(i\sqrt2)^3$ or something? At this point it might be a good idea to look for the _minimal polynomial_ of $i\sqrt2$ over $\Bbb Q$, or just any polynomial. Can you think of a polynomial $f(x)$ with rational coefficients such that $f(i\sqrt2) = 0$?

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure this is the right approach but would we take $a=i\sqrt{2}\rightarrow a^2=-1\cdot 2 \rightarrow a^2+2=0$ so $x^2+2$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Exactly! There is some minor fiddling to show that what you have there is the _minimal_ polynomial (which is the same as showing that that polynomial doesn't factor into smaller degree polynomials with rational coefficients), but otherwise that's it.

Comment: @Arthur How can I conclude that because $x^2+2$ is the minimal polynomial that the elements will be of the form $a+bi\sqrt{2}$? Even in the book I have, it jumps straight from giving a minimal polynomial to saying that all elements will be linear combinations or numbers of that form.

Comment: The only forms that are even possible are like I wrote earlier, something like $a + bi\sqrt2 + c(i\sqrt2)^2+d(i\sqrt2)^3$ (possibly more terms). However, the minimal polynomial being $x^2 + 2$ is saying that $(i\sqrt2)^2 + 2 = 0$ or $(i\sqrt2)^2 = -2$, so you can rewrite $c(i\sqrt2)^2+d(i\sqrt2)^3$ into $-2c-2di\sqrt2$. In other words, any term of order $2$ or higher can have its degree decreased. Finally, you're left with just something of the form $a+bi\sqrt2$. Also, the minimal polynomial being degree $2$ means that you can't do anything more with these lower-order terms.

Comment: For a second example, consider an element $p$ with minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ of order $5$. The field $\Bbb Q(p)$ has elements of the form $a+bp+cp^2+dp^3+ep^4$. Any representation with higher order terms may be reduced by using the minimal polynomial (the polynomial may be rewritten to $p^5 = \cdots$). And there is no more reduction or alternate coefficients possible, because that would imply a relation between $1, p, p^2, p^3, p^4$, which would give rise to a polynomial of degree $4$ or less, which can't happen because the _minimal polynomial_ has degree $5$.

Comment: If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $p(x)$ then an arbitrary polynomial can be written (using the division algorithm for polynomials) as $f(x)=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$ with the degree of $r$ strictly less than the degree of $p$. Then $f(\alpha)=p(\alpha)q(\alpha)+r(\alpha)=r(\alpha)$ - so any polynomial function of $\alpha$ is equal to a polynomial in $\alpha$ of degree less than the degree of its minimum polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it immediately obvious that the extension is degree 2, it helps to write $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ instead of $\Bbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$.